# How to mute ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl()?

Tags: c#, console-application, exchangewebservices

This **AutodiscoverUrl** method  [ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.autodiscoverurl?view=exchange-ews-api)

write too much information into the console. I tried to hide the output using:

```
Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null)`
```

But with no effect.

Is it possible to hide the output somehow ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EWS Managed API doesn't write anything to console by default so you must have enabled tracing in your code (you should post a more complete sample of the code you using) ? so you should probably look a disabling tracing if you not using or use the TraceFlags to define what you want to listen to eg.

```
        service exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.AutodiscoverConfiguration;
```

Comment: You are right, `service.TraceEnabled = false;` solve the issue, thank you.